# Update ng-select item after added new item from modal in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I need to update ng-select in angular 4 after add new value from modal

In console.log I can view the new added item in list, but it didn't reflect in drop-down

Can any one please suggest

I have following code

> city.component.ts

export class CityComponent implements OnInit {

```
public myForm: FormGroup; // our model driven form

public city0: Array<any> = [];

constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.city0=[ {value:'City A',label:'City A'},
    {value:'City B',label:'City B'},
    {value:'City C',label:'City C'},
    {value:'City D',label:'City D'},];

}

add_new_city(model, isValid: boolean){

    this.submitted = true; // set form submit to true

    const data = this.newCityForm.value;
    this.city0.push({
    'value': data.new_city_name,
    'label' : data.new_city_name
    });

}
```

}

> city.component.html

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">City</label>
<div class="col-sm-4">

    <ng-select 
        formControlName="city_name"
        [options]="city0"

        [multiple]="multiple0"
        [allowClear]="true"
        [(ngModel)]="cityName"

        >
    </ng-select>  

</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <button type="button"(click)="openModal(template)">Add New City</button>
</div>

</div>
    <ng-template #template>
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4>Add City</h4>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="new_city_name" >City Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="new_city_name" formControlName="new_city_name">
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <span  class="col-sm-5 ">
                <button type="button"  (click)="modal.hide()">Close</button> 
                <button type="button"  (click)="add_new_city(newForm.value, newForm.valid)>Save</button>
            </span>                                    
        </div>
    </ng-template>
```

Comment: Try injecting ChangeDetectRef and call markForCheck (or something like that) after you update your list.

Comment: I guess by inspecting your code that you have not declared "newCityForm" anywhere and you are trying to get its value. In case If that is also fine, Can you please add a Plunkr?

Comment: @cgTag thanks for quick reply, sure i will try it

Comment: @KIA thanks for quick reply, i will  try  it on Plunkr..